# ¿Cómo debemos considerar una respuesta que termina con un "Si la ayuda de este post te ha servido, buen check verde y flecha arriba son bienvenidos"?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, convenciones-sociales

Según [¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), no se debe usar ningún tipo de firma en el cuerpo de una pregunta (ni respuesta):

> No uses firmas, taglines o saludos.
>
> Cada aporte que hagas ya esta “firmado” con tu tarjeta de usuario en
>   tu perfil. Esta tarjeta forma un enlace permanente a tu página de
>   usuario. Si usas una firma adicional o un tagline, sera removida
>   debido a que creará mas ruido en las preguntas y respuestas.
>
> Tu página de usuario te pertenece a tí - llénala de información sobre
>   tus intereses, enlaces a cosas en las cuales has trabajado o cualquier
>   otra cosa que te interese.

Ahora bien, hoy tenemos un caso de [una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/169513/324) a la pregunta [Colocar función al acabar el juego](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/169508/324), que llevó a una acalorada discusión.

Al finalizar, la respuesta dice:

> Si la ayuda de este post te ha servido, buen check verde y flecha
>   arriba son bienvenidos :)

Esto, pareceria una clara violación de lo declarado al principio.

Para no ensuciar esta discusion, no voy a replicar nada de lo que se dijo en comentarios ni en el chat, pero definitivamente pareceria una línea que, según lo detallado en el primer enlace, debería ser removida.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Esa línea puede ser un buen consejo a seguir, pero no deja de ser una firma que el usuario pone en sus publicaciones y no debería ponerse como se indica en el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Como razones por las que no debería ir en la propia publicación se podría citar que:

- Crea ruido innecesario y hasta se podría considerar spam.
- Realmente es un comentario y no una recomendación que deba ir en la respuesta.
- Es poco elegante (aunque esto será cuestión de gustos).
- Si el usuario acepta la pregunta o vota positivo, deja de tener sentido.

...pero todo esto podría resumirse en una razón simple: esa línea **no aporta nada a la respuesta**. Si se eliminase, la respuesta seguiría teniendo sentido, e incluso sería más fácil de leer.

Comment: Si veis el resto de publicaciones solo hay una más con eso, una firma es un signo de identificación, esa frase no me identifica en absoluto, que no añade nada a la pregunta? bueno, eso sí puede ser

Comment: @enriquemanzanogil Una firma (en el sentido amplio) no tiene por qué identificarte. Podrías poner una cita en plan "_'No basta con alcanzar la sabiduría, es necesario saber utilizarla', Cicerón_", que no te identifica pero se seguiría considerando una firma y no debería permitirse en una respuesta.

Comment: Precisamente tú te has respondido solo, esa frase, es una CITA, si eso tampoco está permitido, que se indique en las normas.

Comment: @enriquemanzanogil pero sí se indica en las normas. La palabra clave es tagline, que es un eslogan o cita corta.

Answer (score 7):

Para mi, en el cuerpo de la respuesta solo debe ir eso, la respuesta. Cosas adicionales lo único que hacen es ensuciar y crear ruido.

Por otro lado, tradicionalmente en toda la red StackExchange las peticiones de votos suelen ser muy mal recibidas, y de hecho suelen generar el efecto contrario, como se puede ver por ejemplo en este post de meta StackExchange:

[Begging for Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes)

En el caso que nos ocupa,a pesar de que el creador de la respuesta se escuda en una definición exacta de `tagline` para considerar que no incumple ninguna norma, para mi si se puede considerar que añadir ese texto al final de todas las respuestas es una firma, léase un texto que se añade a todas las publicaciones.

Si admitimos esto, empezaremos a admitir todo tipo de firmas que no aportan absolutamente nada a las respuestas, generando ruido innecesario.

Por otro lado, se podría argumentar que el texto añadido no incumple las normas de StackOverflow en Español, ya que lo único que hace es añadir un recordatorio de comportamientos deseables en la comunidad. Bajo ese punto de vista, yo podría añadir al final de cada una de mis respuestas todo el texto del centro de ayuda. Obviamente, no sería un *tagline*, pero la cuestión básica es que ensuciaría inecesariamente la respuesta, que es lo principal.

En resumen, creo que no se debe permitir este ni ningún otro texto que se repita en todas las respuestas de un miembro de la comunidad.

Comment: Has visto el resto de respuestas? solo está eso en 2, no es ni un 5%, está muy lejos de "todas"

Answer (score 7):

Dejando de lado de si es un tagline o no y así como el número de respuestas en las que se usa el enunciado en cuestión para mí es claro que no es bien visto **solicitar votos** en el contenido de una respuesta, sin importar si se hace al principio, en medio o al final.

Ahora bien, los consejos dados al final de un escrito califican como saludos y para ser más claros como una despedida.

Por lo que recién se puede ver es todavía peor visto si la petición de votos se coloca de forma tal que parece una firma, tagline, saludo/despedida

*No hagas cosas buenas que parecen malas*

Answer (score -5):

la respuesta es simple, no es una firma, una firma es una [identificación o conducta habitual que te define distintivamente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hyte6ty), asímismo, no es un tagline o un slogan, se ha usado en sólo dos respuestas de no sé exactamente cuántas tiene la cuenta realizadas, no es algo significativo, ni es un indicio de slogan. Ni está en todas las publicaciones, ni promociona ningún negocio, ni es una firma, ya que el hecho de estar en dos publicaciones no es determinante para catalogarlo como tal.....

Comment: Dejando de lado de si es un tagline o no y así como el número de respuestas en las que se usa el enunciado en cuestión para mí es claro que no es bien visto solicitar votos en el contenido de una respuesta.

Comment: Entonces, sigo diciendo, cambiar lo que explica el recorrido de inicio en stackoverflow sería una buena práctica, ya que en ningún sitio dice que esté prohibido algo que no sea de buen gusto como tal, ya que es un término muy ambigüo, y cuando lo pongo es por el hecho de haber precedentes de que la respuesta sea la que se elige pero la pregunta nunca se cierra...

Comment: El recorrido de inicio tiene lo mínimo indispensable pensando en alguien que aún no ha publicado nada aquí. Lo básico sobre cómo responder están en [answer] y algunas otras cosas en [meta-tag:faq]. Definitivamente hay mucho por hacer, mientras tanto para eso está [meta].